# Using python class to wrap shared variables vs. using global / nonlocal?

Tags: python, class, variables, global

I'm finding it useful to create an empty class to wrap variables that I wish to share between different functions:

```
# using a class as a namespace wrapper for containing and sharing variables
class shared_variables:
    pass

shared = shared_variables()
shared.var1 = 'boo'
shared.var2 = 'baa'
```

This provides easy access to shared top-level variables without having to reference them into local functions by using the 'global' keyword.

Are there any drawbacks (performance or otherwise) of using a container class vs. using the 'global' / 'non-local' keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach of the shared module is idiomatic. I can't speak to what's more efficient in terms of python internals, but once the class is constructed there should be no speed penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be any drawback if you do as you ay.

You could also use closures; read for instance:

- http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure
- http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/python-closures-explained.html
- http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html

It can provide an elegant way of achieving such a goal in some circumstances. If you want to change the values of the shared variables, you should put them in some mutable type (which may already be the case if you are working with lists, dictionaries, sets, etc.)

Here is a quick example:

```
def initialize():
  var1 = ['boo']
  var2 = ['baa']
  def f1(x):
    var2[0] = var1[0]
    var1[0] = x
  def f2():
    print(var1, var2)
  return f1, f2

f1, f2 = initialize()

f2()
f1("test")
f2()
```